# Can't boot Voyager Linux based on Xubuntu

Tags: command-line, boot, xfce, xubuntu

I recently installed Voyager Linux, an linux distribution based on Xubuntu. The problem is that I cant boot it anymore. I have a dual boot system with Windows 8.1, but that's not the problem. I installed the latest build of WPS Office a16 I think, but when installing things got weird, and apps from the dock started to disappear. I wasn't able to restart, so I turned off the notebook. Next time, it wont boot, staying at this screen:

[image: pic]

I already did some things, but with no results. I already checked if there were some packages missing or something with [this guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html?m=1)
with no effect. I also tried:

```
apt-get install xfce4
```

because I thought the desktop files may be missing, and it installed some packages, 50 MB. But after starting again the os, no results, same problem. I don't know what is going on, I researched a lot, but nothing related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your installing the  "latest build of WPS Office a16 I think" caused problems. Can you remove (purge?) it and see if anything's fixed?

Your screenshot indicates that "LightDM" failed, maybe reinstall / reconfigure that might help too. It's not normally a part of XFCE, maybe Voyager uses it (XFCE uses the XFWM4 window manager), so maybe install/reinstall/reconfigure xfwm4 might help too.

Comment: I forgot to add the link of WPS Office suite, and it was the a15 version: http://wps-community.org/

Comment: And also, I did 
    apt-get remove wps-office (it did remove the package)
with no result of getting Voyager working, maybe using purge works better?

Comment: I will try reconfiguring LightDM, and report back.

Comment: When I try to run sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm I get: Unable to resolve host xubuntu

Comment: I'm not sure about the resolve host part, connecting with an ethernet cable may help if it's not setting up wifi properly. I'd hate to recommend re-installing, but you should have a good backup of any data you'd like to keep anyway

Comment: My wifi and the internet connection through it is working perfectly. I can load webpages, etc. Thats why I dont know why its telling me the host part :/
I have a feeling that I will need to reinstall. Is a fresh install, no important data so far ;)

Comment: I deleted lightdm with sudo apt-get remove lightdm and freed like 550 KB. Then, I did sudo apt-get install lightdm and it installed like 55MB of data. I will start the actual system and report if it worked. Also, I forgot to add that I added a exit line at the file that manages the NTP internet sync time (/etc/default/ntpdate), to deactivate it (I first thought it was the network interface not setting up) from this http://serverfault.com/questions/103224/disable-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu

Comment: Now I see the login screen, but I cant login, even as a guest. It says: Failed to start session

Comment: If you login to a plain terminal sometimes `startx` will get things going once... A fresh install does make it easier to start again... maybe the WPS Office suite was from an odd repo or PPA & incompatible with Voyager, I know that can be a fast & easy way to mix up lots of systems. WPS Office isn't in the regular Ubuntu or Mint or getdeb.net repos

Comment: Well, I got tired of it, so I reinstalled the OS. Everything working fine now :D Thanks for your help.